When is a map a relative cell complex?
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cofibrantly generated model category (which is generated by $\mathscr{I}$ and $\mathscr{J}$), and $X\times I$ a cylinder object of a finite $\mathscr{I}$-cell complex $X$, which means there is a decomposition
$$X\amalg X\xrightarrow{(i_0,i_1)} X\times I \xrightarrow{r} X$$
such that $r\circ (i_0,i_1)=(\mathsf{id}_X,\mathsf{id}_X)$, i.e., $r\circ i_0=r\circ i_1=\mathsf{id}_X$, and $(i_0,i_1)$ is a cofibration, $r$ is a weak equivalence.
Then, is it possible to show that the map $(i_0,i_1)\colon X\amalg X\to X\times I$ is a relative finite $\mathscr{I}$-cell complex, like in $\mathbf{Top}$?
A more general question is, is it possible to show that any cofibration $X\to Y$ between $\mathscr{I}$-cell complexes $X,Y$ is a relative $\mathscr{I}$-cell complex?
